# Can't detect card index correctly using react-native-card-stack-swiper?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I used onSwiped event of CardStack to detect card index as it said on docs it receives the index of the swiped card but this is not the same index as the data I passed to. When I printed the indexes I realized that for the same card index changes, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the implementation of the package the index for the same card changes when loop prop of CardStack is true and for detecting index I used buttons to swipe to right and left and a custom index to track card index with loop prop of false which is the default, for anyone may encounter this issue here is what I did

```
const [cardIndex, setCardIndex] = useState(0);
// pass it to CardStack ref
const swiperRef = useRef();

const onLeftButtonClick = () => {
    if(cardIndex > 0) {
        setCardIndex(cardIndex - 1);
        swiperRef.current.goBackFromRight();
    }
}

const onRightButtonClick = () => {
    // data used to render cards 
    if(cardIndex < data.length - 1) {
        setCardIndex(cardIndex + 1);
        swiperRef.current.swipeLeft();
    }
}
```